# Break-even point for OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

It seems that OSGi is a hot term these days. Many [benefits](http://www.osgi.org/About/WhyOSGi) are invoked:

- Reduced Complexity
- Reuse
- Easy deployment
- Versioning

(etc)

I'm asking for a very specific use case - *small to medium-sized web applications*. What benefits would OSGi bring for those? It is actually worth it?

Comment: This is subjective, but not CW material. I'm going to choose the answer with the best arguments.

Comment: In agreement with Partly Cloudy's answer, "reduced complexity" is debatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll hazard a **NO**, even though I'm a big fan of OSGi.  Unless you're working with other OSGi bundles or you have a specific problem that you can't easily solve without this sledgehammer.

The benefit is elegant classpath separation (IMHO).  If you need different versions of the same JAR/class, say because you're upgrading certain portions of an app while it's running, or because you are combining a lot of 3rd party modules, then OSGi is great.

That's not an easy thing to achieve, and it's not made easy with OSGi.  It's made clean, but at a cost of another layer in the environment stack.  And a lot of work to learn and maintain.

Not to mention the documentation isn't particularly beginner-friendly.

I suggest learning about it -- building Eclipse plugins is one very good way -- but not building it in to your dev plan until you know it well.

Answer (score 7):

I would say as always "it depends".

**Your environment**

Consider an existing team with no OSGI experience(who proudly consider themselves as experienced developers who "get things done". There's a chance that they'll experience a major pain or a slow start.

MANY(more than you might think) developers are not familiar with build tools such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), and when they are they only use limited features of those build tools.

Creating OSGI bundles is best accomplished with [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org), [Ant tasks](http://www.aqute.biz/Code/Bnd) or [Maven BND plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) VS a script or a manually written manifest for the jar archive.

**Small applications**

For small applications, OSGI introduces unnecessary complexity while you could use dynamic languages such as [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), etc. or a plugin framework such as [JPF](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) or the [SPI](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=49083). You could also go directly with reflection and a simple custom classloader.

**Big applications**

Big applications might benefit from OSGI, especially when they are written from scratch. IMHO integrating OSGI in an existing application is more like introducing a patch for provide a modular architecture.

From my experience, after rewriting many applications, it's better to think about the modularity at the early days of a project.

**Other concerns**

*Deployment* :
It is the same in any applications. If you're used to deploy Java Web Start applications, deployment is not a concern. If you're used to OSGI, deployment shouldn't be a concern.

There are always problems once in a while in any application when it comes to deploying it in production, which is natural.

*Versioning* :
There are many ways to provide versioning in an application. But if you only use versioning as "information" vs as a tool(manage dependencies requirement), versioning is not a concern.

*Reuse* : 
When using OSGI you tend to write your code for reuse, but any well written API is designed with code reuse in mind.

Eclipse is a number one example of a successful big application written with OSGI. There are other big/nice tools which don't use OSGI and are modular.

**Conclusion**

In many modular frameworks, it's difficult to handle dependencies, stop/start/uninstall/install features at runtime, without restarting the application. You play with a custom classloader, shutdown and startup hooks, etc.

OSGI gives you such flexibility at a minor cost IMHO.